# Viewport not being recognized

Tags: css, viewport

I'm working on making a site mobile friendly, and when I put in the meta tag for viewport it's not recognizing it at all.

I'm still working on media queries, but the viewport isn't doing anything at all.

Site: http://gc200298785.computerstudi.es/test/

Source Code: view-source:http://gc200298785.computerstudi.es/test/

Thank you in advance!
Kayley

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine only. I noticed your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
/*main*/
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    max-width: 90%;
    padding: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a .inside-container {
    max-width: 25%;
}
nav {
    width: 25%;
}
nav li{
    display: inline;
}
#menu {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

}

add below the code in your css

```
.container, #paper, #landing, #paper-bottom{width 100%;}
```

Comment: @anglimmass Even after adding that still looks like this on my phone.

http://i.imgur.com/BlZ7zK7.png

Comment: I'm also getting this from google mobile friendly test.

"Size content to viewport
The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience.
The page content is 1,142 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 320 CSS pixels wide. The following elements fall outside the viewport:"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Also best practise is to start your css as mobile/ responsive, so in other words dont wrap it in a media query.

Then for desktop start a media query under the main mobile/ responsive css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) //or what ever size you want {
// insert your styles here
}
```

You will find that it is a lot easier to approach your development this way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, this is already an existing site. If I had built it I would have made it responsive to begin with.